# Does this equation have an explicit solution?

Tags: polynomials

I have ended up needing to solve the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{p \left(n (1-p)^n-2 (1-p)^n+n+2\right)+2
   \left((1-p)^n-1\right) -n p^2 }{(n-2)(p-1)} =  \frac{n p-1}{(n-1)}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is an integer that is strictly greater than $3$, and $p$ is a real number in the  $(0, 1)$ interval. While I can solve this for $p$ after plugging in particular values of $n$, I have not been able to solve it for $p$ in general. Is this possible in principle?

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: For $n \geq 5$, the prospects are bleak.  One of the counter-indications is [the Abel-Ruffini Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be relevant. Is it hard to use this to show that it can't be solved?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by *"can't be solved"*. The comment above suggests that you're very unlikely to find any expression with just some square roots, powers and fractions.

Answer (score 0):

In principle is not possible. I made *Mathematica* solve the equation for $p\in(0,1)$ for a few hundred of $n$-value, then looked for a fit and found
$$p_n=\frac{5.7358}{6.25529 n-0.424686}$$
which is quite accurate
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r|r}
 n & actual\;root & p_n&error \;percentage (\%)\\
\hline
 4 & 0.233196 & 0.233196 & 1.52\times 10^{-6} \\
 204 & 0.00449659 & 0.00449636 & 0.00525814 \\
 404 & 0.00227021 & 0.00227006 & 0.00644436 \\
 604 & 0.00151841 & 0.0015183 & 0.00684953 \\
 804 & 0.00114066 & 0.00114058 & 0.00705397 \\
 1004 & 0.000913426 & 0.00091336 & 0.00717725 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Just a suggestion: It would be nice to show the error in the calculated $p_n$ (perhaps as a percentage of the actual root) to show how accurate it is :)

Comment: I edited and the results are amazing. I had to multiply by $100$ to avoid too many zeros. I am satisfied by this result, because the given equations were not tractable in the general case. With this formula one gets an approximation in a snap. @an4s

Comment: It is quite interesting that the %age error increases as $n$ becomes larger. I wonder when $n\to\infty$, whether $\text{error}\to100\%$.

Comment: Not easy to prove, since we don't have a closed form for the actual solutions. Using the approximation given by *Mathematica*, for $n=10^{10}$ the percentage is still $0.00766357\%$. Larger values give a negative root, therefore the 'formula' no longer works

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. NB The solution is also not far from $p = 1/n$.